# Layer Group cannot be added into QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, group-layer

I am having a problem with adding a layer group into QGIS, where upon making a connection to the server in QGIS, the layer group does not appear. I see only the layers that make up that layer group. Can someone tell me what might be the problem or what I might be missing?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what URL did you use in QGIS to set up the WMS?

Comment: Hi, I used this URL: https://geo.shmu.sk/geoserver/EF/wms?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0

Comment: Please don't use comments to add requested details/info. Edit your question to include it so everything is in one place

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of this is that you have used a workspace specific `GetCapabilities` request to connect QGIS to GeoServer and that your layer group is not in that workspace.

There are two fixes, first you could move your layer group to the workspace. There is a drop down on the `Layer Group` page where you can select it.

[image]

Secondly (and probably better) is to use the generic `GetCapabilities` link that you can find on the right side of the front page of GeoServer.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ian, I did set up store connection in group layer settings, when I first made it

Comment: can you see the group layer in the getcapabilities response you get?\

Comment: No, I dont see the group layer in getcapabilities, olny in layer preview - thru OpenLayers, where I can view it

Comment: then it is not in that workspace

Comment: Actually, I found it in the getcapabilities responce, so its in there, it its just doesnt shows for some reason

Comment: In that case is there a scale denominator set or could the projection be wrong